# Generate 3D surface parametrization starting from 2D parametrization

Tags: curves, surfaces, parametrization

Consider the following parametrisation of a flower-like domain, where $R=0.4$ and $r=0.2$:

$\theta \mapsto [(R+r\cos(6\pi\theta))\cos(2\pi \theta), (R+r\cos(6\pi \theta))\sin(2\pi \theta)]$
which gives the following shape:

[image]

I'd like to get the three dimensional version of this: imagine the surface formed by rotating this figure and obtaining something which looks like a sphere but with many

Comment: Should the $x$ be $\theta$? With angular frequencies $6\pi$ and $2\pi$ I would expect 3 'points' not 8?

Comment: To clarify: do you want a sphere with many similar isolated spikes? Or do you want the version of this revolved around an axis? If you revolve it around the vertical axis, the non-vertical spikes will sweep out circles.

Comment: @Paul Yes, fixed. Sorry for the typo

Comment: @TomKern  A sphere with many similar isolated spikes would be perfect.

Comment: $6\pi\theta$ should be $16\pi\theta$ to get the $8$-spiked curve (with $\theta\in[0,1]$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose we take the curve $\mathcal C$, parameterized by

$$\begin{cases}
x(\theta) = (R+r\cos(16\pi\theta)) \cos(2\pi\theta) \\
y(\theta) = (R+r\cos(16\pi\theta)) \sin(2\pi\theta)
\end{cases}$$

with $R=0.4$, $r=0.2$, and $\theta\in[0,1]$, and revolve it about the $x$-axis. Consider a cross section of the resulting surface taken perpendicular to the $x$-axis at $x=x_0\in\left[-\frac35,\frac35\right]$. It's easy to show that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le \frac35$.

In the plane of the cross section, solve $x(\theta_0)=x_0$ for $\theta_0$ and plug the solution (there are multiple depending on your choice of $x_0$) into the parametric equations for $\mathcal C$. $x(\theta_0)$ and $y(\theta_0)$ define a circle in the cross sectional plane centered at $(x_0,0,0)$ and with radius $y(\theta_0)$. We can parameterize this circle by the 3D parametric curve,

$$\begin{cases}
x'(\phi) = x(\theta_0) \\
y'(\phi) = y(\theta_0) \cos(2\pi\phi) \\
z'(\phi) = y(\theta_0) \sin(2\pi\phi)
\end{cases}$$

with $\phi\in[0,1]$.

It follows that the complete surface is parameterized by

$$\begin{cases}
x(\theta,\phi) = x(\theta) \\
y(\theta,\phi) = y(\theta) \cos(\pi \phi) \\
z(\theta,\phi) = y(\theta) \sin(\pi \phi)
\end{cases}$$

with $(\theta,\phi)\in[0,1]^2$.

The figure shows $\mathcal C$ (red) plotted in the plane $z=0$, the surface of revolution, and one of the circles (green) traced out by revolving a point on $\mathcal C$ about the $x$-axis (rendered with $\theta_0\approx0.159$, i.e. in the plane $x=0.2$, which happens to correspond to $3$ distinct circles at $6$ distinct values of $\theta_0$).

[image]

Comment: Looking at the comments I think the questioner wants a 3D version of the 2D picture., A virus like shape

Comment: Oh you are right, I overlooked OP's reply to Tom. I assume the spikes would be uniformly shaped, and be uniformly and symmetrically distributed to have a total of $16$ spikes. Probably some modified version of spherical coordinates will work. @bobinthebox can you confirm?

Comment: @user170231 Yes, exactly! A virus-like shape was what I was looking for. I tried to get that using your approach but I'm not able. If you could provide that a parametrisation of that it would be amazing.

Comment: I found a similar-looking shape [here](https://wolfram.com/xid/0dqtnmk2h2g-bjrx15) (the link *should* jump to a specific example, but if not, it's the first one under "Neat examples") plotted in spherical coordinates, but I've been so far unable to modify it to more closely resemble the surface you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks anyway for the references! How can I play in order to test plots of different parametrisations like the one you posted here?

Comment: I made the plot of the surface and curves in Mathematica. Desmos may be a cheaper option. See for instance https://www.desmos.com/calculator/usy8hfrtbx